# How to solve such a error after upgrading the Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get an error like:

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry'
```

after upgraded the gradle plugin from **`2.3.0`** to **`3.3.3`** and gradle from **`4.10.1`** to **`4.10.2`**.

How can I solve such a bug?

Comment: I think your gradle version is still lowest current gradle is 7.0.2 I think

Comment: yes, agree with you. But the Gradle version of the android application is 3.3.3. I only provide an SDK.